# SmartLock saves Facebook credentials without asking

Tags: android, facebook, credentials, password-storage, google-smartlockpasswords

When the app successfully logins in via Facebook it begins to save the credentials. This should ask the user if they want to save it with SmartLock or not, but it's being saved automatically.

Inside the save callback I get a success with no resolution. It should not be a success, and it should contain a resolution to allow prompting the user to save.

Is there any reason why this is, or any way to get the functionality I want?

-Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password-less "credentials" can be saved without needing to prompt the user (i.e., credential built with `.setAccountType` in place of `.setPassword`) if the identifier on the credential matches a Google Account on the device.

And in general, when the user returns on another device, user can be immediately signed back in if they are using an account for the app that matches one on the device, since such credentials will come with a [token you can use for auth](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/idtoken-auth). For example, gmail user whose account is active on a device (and could otherwise receive email, such as for a password reset flow), can be signed in to apps without need extra UI or to trigger a Facebook flow unnecessarily to get a different token.

In the past, the API required prompts to save any information, but we found in user research testing that minimizing the dialogs users encounter reduces confusion, streamlines the user experience, and promotes security best practices (such as using tokens from authoritative issuers when relying on email-based identifiers).

Comment: Let me know if that answers your concerns/questions?

Comment: Just so I understand, if my Google account on my phone is myAccount@gmail.com and I use my Facebook account with the email myAccount@gmail.com to sign in, I will not get a prompt since the identifier is the same. But if my Facebook account used an email such as myOtherAccount@gmail.com, I would be prompted to save the Facebook credentials since the identifier is different. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct, if email address does not match, user will have to pick and confirm which Google Account to save the information with

Comment: Can this saved information be tempered either by rooting the phone or using any other mechanism?